# How can the X-59 fly faster than the speed of sound without producing sonic booms?

Tags: aircraft-design, supersonic, nasa, lockheed-martin-x-59-quesst

Lately, NASA and Lockheed Martin revealed the X-59 which looks amazing. I read this [article](https://www.nasa.gov/image-article/nasa-supercomputers-visualize-quieter-supersonic-flight-2/#:%7E:text=NASA%27s%20X%2D59%20Quiet%20SuperSonic,disruptive%20to%20humans%20and%20animals.) from NASA which already gives some insights of the X-59. The article claims that it will fly faster than the speed of sound without producing sonic booms like here:

> NASA’s X-59 Quiet SuperSonic Technology X-plane is designed to fly
> faster than the speed of sound without producing sonic booms – loud,
> startling noises which can be disruptive to humans and animals.

I was wondering if anyone could explain in some way how this is even possible. I can imagine it must have a specific design, but maybe anyone could explain how this works? Then I'm really curious if this will also happen to fighter jets, since it may be nice advantage to be quite in the sky, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer to the title, in short, it doesn't. The plane flies a little slower than the Concorde and still makes a sonic boom, just that they've managed to make it much quieter. You cannot eliminate a sonic shock wave. That is just pure and simple physics. You can only attempt to minimize the shock wave, by design of the airplane's parts that make the shock waves happen. The long pointy nose, sharp-edged high sweepback wings, no protrusions, etc. Some experimental designs try to direct most of the wave upwards, but there will still be an audible sonic "thump" as they call it